# Filter duplicates from a list to populate ComboBox

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I've been looking for a way to filter out duplicates from a list to populate a form, but so far all I have found are to create a duplicate list with either a `Hashset` or other methods that involve grouping the duplicates into  separate list, however I'm not interested in keeping the extras.

Currently what I'm getting in my combobox is:

```
123
123
456
456
789
789
```

etc...
Trouble is, I'm collecting the data in models (or classes) as such:

```
List<ModelName>

ModelName<1>
{
   string Name = Bob;
   int Number = 123;
}
ModelName<2>
{
   string Name = Jim;
   int Number = 123;
}
ModelName<3>
{
   string Name = Bob;
   int Number = 456;
}
```

Is there a way to fill a list with unique classes:

```
ModelName<1>
{
    Name; 
    Number;
}
ModelName<2>
{
    Name;
}
ModelName<3>
{
    Number;
}
```

and just filter out and dispose of any double ups?

Comment: what kind of list you have

Comment: As far as "unique" classes go, you could use dynamic types for that. Any property not assigned would simply return null.

Comment: I find it hard to understand the edited question. Are _Bob/123_ equal to _Jim/123_ because they share the same number? And are _Bob/123_ equal to _Bob/456_ because they share the same name? Then, if equality is transitive as it should be, you can infer that _Jim/123_  is equal to _Bob/456_: _Bob/456 == Bob/123 == Jim/123_. But then all items are duplicates. To get a good answer to your question you need to more precisely define how you define "double ups".

Comment: Good point @MartinLiversage This definitely seems like a bizarre example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the LINQ [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operator to remove duplicates from a collection:

```
var listWithoutDuplicates = listWithDuplicates.Distinct().ToList();
```

If you want to customize the way elements are compared for equality you can use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that requires an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In your case, if you want to define "equality" as having the same value of the `Location` property you can use this `EqualityComparer`:

```
class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ClassName> {

  public Boolean Equals(ClassName x, ClassName y) {
    return Equals(x.Location, y.Location);
  }

  public Int32 GetHashCode(ClassName obj) {
    return obj.Location.GetHashCode();
  }

}
```

And to get distinct items by location:

```
var listWithoutDuplicates = listWithDuplicates.Distinct(new EqualityComparer).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't work. In his example, the person's names are not equal, although the id's are.

Comment: @B2K: The question has been edited quite a bit after I wrote my answer. The problem is that I do not understand the edited question. So I have decided to leave my answer on how to use `Distinct` with an `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it did answer the original question, and you have also pointed out the (quite big) flaws of the new question

Answer (score 4):

```
yourList.GroupBy(x => x.Location).Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: Asker's code did not include a Location. @B2K suggested an edit to `Number`, but it was rejected.

Comment: @PatrickM: Look at the edit history of the question. Initially, the question mentioned a `Location` property.

Answer (score 1):

Use list.distinct() and populate a list

```
  List<int> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();
```